# Determine Size of Multidimensional Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix, count

I am new to Swift and am struggling to work out how to determine the size of a multidimensional array.

I can use the count function for single arrays, however when i create a matrix/multidimensional array, the output for the count call just gives a single value.

```
var a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
var c: Int
c = a.count
print(c)

2
```

The above matrix 'a' clearly has 2 rows and 3 columns, is there any way to  output this correct size.

In Matlab this is a simple task with the following line of code,

```
a = [1,2,3;3,4,5]
size(a)
ans =
2 3
```

Is there a simple equivalent in Swift

I have looked high and low for a solution and cant seem to find exactly what i am after.

Thanks 
- HB

Answer (score 18):

Because 2D arrays in swift can have subarrays with different lengths. There is no "matrix" type.

```
let arr = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [1,2,3],
    [2,3,4,5],
]
```

So the concept of "rows" and "columns" does not exist. There's only `count`.

If you want to count all the elements in the subarrays, (in the above case, 12), you can flat map it and then `count`:

```
arr.flatMap { $0 }.count
```

If you are sure that your array is a matrix, you can do this:

```
let rows = arr.count
let columns = arr[0].count // 0 is an arbitrary value
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ask the size of a specific row of your array to get column sizes :

```
print("\(a.count) \(a[0].count)")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the length of 2D array which in this case the number of rows (or # of subarrays Ex.[1,2,3]) you may use this trick: # of total elements that can be found using:
`a.flatMap { $0 }.count    //a is the array name`

over # of elements in one row using:

`a[0].count //so elemints has to be equal in each subarray`

so your code to get the length of 2D array  ***with equal number of element in each subarray***  and store it in constant arrayLength is:

```
let arrayLength = (((a.flatMap { $0 }.count ) / (a[0].count)))  //a is the array name
```